# Deleting files and folders in Program File folder

Tags: powershell

I have been using

```
remove-item -path C:\...
```

to remove folders and files but I recently was trying to remove a file in the Program Files folder and I get an error:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument 'Files\New'.

Tried to see if it is just syntax but it doesn't seem to be.

```
remove-item -path C:\Program Files\New -force
```

also have one in case its a 64-bit machine that is

```
remove-item -path C:\Program Files (x86)\New -force
```

both don't work. All my other `remove-item` have worked.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Try putting quotes around the path, like `remove-item -path "C:\Program Files\New" -force`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command:

```
remove-item -path C:\Program Files\New -force
```

is parsed into a string parameter `-path` with value `C:\Program` and a switch parameter `-force`. There is an additional part in your command `Files\New`. It doesn't start with a dash, so PowerShell tries to bind it to any positional parameters but it can't, so it says:

`A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument 'Files\New'`

Anytime you have spaces in your argument, you have to put single or double quotes around it:

```
remove-item -path "C:\Program Files\New" -force
```

Comment: You should get into the habit of using single quotes for this, not double.  You're not interpreting expressions in the string, at least not intentionally - and you don't want to do it accidentally.

Comment: @RyanBemrose - Maybe, but does it really hurt? I suddenly remember I should use `ls "$env:programfiles\windows NT" ` rather that `C:\Program Files` and now I have to change the quotes as well.

Comment: No, it doesn't hurt, right up to that day far in the future where it *does* hurt because you have a dollar sign or backtick in your string and the only symptom is "My string is having random characters replaced or go missing" and you're so used to using double quotes for everything that you spend an hour trying to figure out why it's broken, because it just never occurred to you to use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

@fvu's recommendation is correct.  You need quotes around any path name with spaces.

```
remove-item -path 'C:\Program Files\New' -force
```

Powershell is smart enough to know when you put something like `remove-item -path c:\temp` that the thing after "-path" should be a string, so PS treats it like a string.  But it can't do that with spaces, because spaces are also the delimiter between arguments.  So the solution is to explicitly make it a string.

In this case there is no difference between single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`).  The latter is used if you need to inject Powershell variables into the string.  Because you're not doing that, I suggest single.